# SVN Checkout features

Tags: svn, svnkit, svn-checkout

I am implementing `SVN checkout` operation in our project.

Currently I have decided to implement following 2 features

```
1) Checkout latest revision
2) Checkout from a specific revision
```

What are the other features SVN checkout operations has?
What are more features that I need to implement for SVN checkout?

Any thoughts will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're writing some kind of Subversion client you absolutely need to read the Subversion book, or at least the information provided by `svn help`. It's crazy to just ask in a forum.

Answer (score 0):

You also have other options in [`svn co`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svn.c.checkout):

- sparse checkout ([`svn co --depth`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.depth))
- preview ([`svn co --dry-run`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.depth))
- ignore external ([svn co --ignore-externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.ignore_externals)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `svn co --help` which will show all the available options.